# Second HDMI monitor not recognised in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04, only to find that my second external HDMI-connected monitor is not recognised in this new OS version.

My machine is a Lenovo G510 essential, with no NVIDIA GPU (so it is not an nvidia driver issue as the answer to a similar question) and up to the 19.10 version I had no problem connecting 2 monitors to it.

I have already tried to add the HDMI connection via xrandr and arandr, but had no success. What is strange is that the monitor does not seem disconnected, I just get a black screen (like it is connected but with no input) and nothing is shown on it. My search has shown that this is a known bug, but no answer has helped fix that yet.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What does `xrandr --query` say?

Comment: Just a small troubleshooting step.  Have you tried both monitors individually to make sure it is not a cable/hardware issue.  Both monitors individually in both ports.

Comment: @SHawarden xrandr says: "HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)"

Comment: @walttheboss I am confident that this is not a hardware issue since it happened exactly after updating to 20.04 while with 19.10 I had everything in place. Also, HDMI is seen by xrandr, and if the screen was faulty I would be able to move my cursor there but no my computer acts as if only one screen is connected.

Comment: As they are, check `xrandr --verbose` then swap the monitor connections and run it again. Is the same data appearing on for HDMI-1 and presumably 0? Also, do not just assume anything should work, just because it used to. Eliminate the obvious. A cable could be loose or broken. The monitor could also have died in ways you might not expect or assunme. Can you like to the known bug listing?

Comment: @SHawarden I have confirmed that my second screen works via a second computer, and I repeat, that if the cable was faulty I would have been getting a message from the screen similar to 'HDMI port not connected'.  As for the verbose output: It looks like he following:

HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
 Identifier: 0x44
 Timestamp:  1616979
 Subpixel:   unknown
 Clones:    
 CRTCs:      1 0 2
 Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
             0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
             0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
(cont)

Comment: filter: 
 max bpc: 12 
  range: (8, 12)
 content type: No Data 
  supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
 Colorspace: Default 
  supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
 aspect ratio: Automatic 
  supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
 Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
  supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
 audio: auto 
  supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
 link-status: Good 
  supported: Good, Bad

Comment: CONNECTOR_ID: 76 
  supported: 76
 non-desktop: 0 
  range: (0, 1)